# Problem with displaying photo from database on page

Tags: php, css, sql

I have problem with displaying photo from database on the page. I made a path in database column image_src = "../GameForest/gamephoto/gta5.jpg". And path is correct I checked it several times.

**//This is a class that displaying all the data from the database**

```
<?php
    class Game extends Dbh {

        public function gameDiv() {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT g.game_id, g.game_name, g.image_src, g.genre_id, g.developer_id, g.release_date, g.platfrom_id, g.game_price,  g.game_description, g.processor, g.graphic, g.ram\n" . "FROM game AS g\n" . "LEFT JOIN genre AS z\n" . "ON g.genre_id = z.id WHERE game_id = '$id'");
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

                echo "<div class='gameName'><h2>" . $row['game_name'] . "</h2></div>";

                echo "<div class='buying'><p>" . $row['game_price'] . "&euro;</p><a href='bought.php'><button>Buy Game</button></a></div>";


//This next echo is for displaying photo from database:
                echo "<div class='gamePhoto'><img>" . $row['image_src'] . "</img></div>";

                echo "<div class='gameGenre'><b>Genre: </b><p>" . $row['genre_id'] . "</p></div>";

                echo "<div class='gameDeveloper'><b>Created by: </b><p>" . $row['developer_id'] . "</p></div>";

                echo "<div class='gamePlatform'><b>Platform: </b><p>" . $row['platfrom_id'] . "</p></div>";

                echo "<div class='gameRdate'><b>Release date: </b><p>" . $row['release_date'] . "</p></div>";

                echo "<div class='gameDescription'><b>Description: </b><p>" . $row['game_description'] . "</p></div>";

                echo "<div class='sysRequirements'><p>Recommended System Requirements:</p><b>Processor:</b><p>" . $row['processor'] . "</p>" . "  Heading <b>Graphic:</b><p>" . $row['graphic'] . "</p>" . " <b>RAM:</b><p>" . $row['ram'] . "</p>";
            }
        }
}

**//This is instance for previous class:**
<?php
    #istance for printing information about a Game
    $game = new Game;
    echo $game->gameDiv();
?>

**//This is CSS code of that photo:**

.gamePhoto {
        margin: 10px 0 20px 10%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 400px;
        float: left;
    }

    .gamePhoto img {
        width: 500px;
        height: 600px;    
    }

?>
```

I expect that there is a picture from database but I get only a gray frame where the image should actually be below that it writes "../GameForest/gamephoto/gta5.jpg" (the path I wrote in the base).
    The rest of the database data are displayed normally it's just a problem with images.
    On the other page (and other class) the same picture from the same database is normally displayed and I have no problem.

Comment: if you wanna show an image you have to do it like this `<img src='path'/>` and replace with your path. but you do it wrong

Answer (score 2):

img is inline block，use it like `<img src="" />`

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<img>" . $row['image_src'] . "</img>
```

to this

```
<img src=" . $row['image_src'] . ">
```